# SQLAlchemy: Relationship Field Values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three [MySQL] tables: Person, Role, PersonRole

```
class Person(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    full_name = Column(String(120), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(128))
    username = Column(String(50))
    last_modified = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False,
                           server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))

    roles = relationship('Role',
                         secondary='person_role',
                         primaryjoin="and_(Person.id==PersonRole.person_id,"
                                     "Role.active==True,"
                                     "PersonRole.active==True)",
                         back_populates='people')

    def __repr__(self):
        """String representation."""
        return '''<Person(id='%s', full_name='%s')>''' % (
            str(self.id), str(self.full_name)
        )


class Role(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), Sequence('role_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    role_name = Column(String(16))
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    last_modified = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False,
                           server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))

    users = relationship('Person',
                         secondary='person_role',
                         primaryjoin="and_(Role.id==PersonRole.role_id,"
                                     "Role.active==True,"
                                     "PersonRole.active==True)",
                         back_populates='roles')

    def __repr__(self):
        """String representation."""
        return '''<Role(role_id='%s', role_name='%s')>''' % (
            str(self.role_id), str(self.role_name)
        )


class PersonRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person_role'

    ds_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                   ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    role_id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True),
                     ForeignKey('role.id'), primary_key=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    last_modified = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False,
                           server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP,
                     server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

Retrieving a Person like so:

...session setup as `s`...

```
person = s.query(Person).get(123)
```

and to list out their roles:

```
for role in person.roles:
    print(role.id, role.role_name, role.active)
```

Now, in each table there is an `active` column. This is to keep track of an [shocker] active status as we dont want to remove data from the table, merely keep it's state. Now to the two issues which have kept me from using SQLAlchemy altogether and has me writing and executing SQL manually -

1. The `active` portion in the final loop though displays the active state of `role.active` and not that of the actual relationship, `person_role.active`.
2. Removing a role will remove the relationship row instead of performing the desired action, `person_role.active = 0`
3. Even if I deactivate the relationship, adding it again will set off the `Duplicate Key` error.

Is there a sane, valid way to go about accomplishing this *without* restructuring my data?

---

Edit for further clarification:

The two main tables in this case are `person` and `person_role`. Person is the main table which holds our users. PersonRole holds the roles a person actually has, in the form of `person.id` to `role.id`. The Role table is merely a lookup table for the Role definition (to get the names).

I suppose what I want is a way to intercept how the ORM actually adds/removes the data. Adding should [more-or-less] do an "upsert" and removing should basically run a update query like: `update person_role set active = 0 where person_id = %s and role_id = %s`.

I have read a lot of the docs but tend to get lost in the terminologies. :S

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understood your problems, but let me try to help you:

**1)** This is the one I am most confused with: `person.roles` maps to a collection of `Role` entities. Ain't that what you expect?

**2, 3)** You have set up a relationship between Person and Role, using PersonRole as secondary. Deactivating means setting `PersonRole.status` to *inactive*, not removing it. Trying to add it again will show a `Duplicate Key` error indeed!

I think you want to run a query to load a `PersonRole` entity by `ds_id` and `role_id`, update its status to *active* and persist changes. I understand that sometimes this may be tedious to perform, so maybe a immediate solution that would not require you to move data around would be to map `Person` and `Role` to `PersonRole`. So, in spite of having `Person.roles` you would have `Person.personRoles`, so you have access to `PersonRole` entities and may set its status.

Of course this is a very immediate solution. SQLAlchemy is extremely featured so maybe you can intercept the Person.roles removal and customize its behaviour to set `PersonRole` to *inactive*. You may want to read more about [cascading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html) on the docs as well.

Hope I was able to clarify things a little :)

Comment: Yeah, I can understand the confusion. I probably did a pretty bad job of explaining. Let me see if I can clear it up a bit.

Comment: I understand. You want to let SQLAlchemy deal with setting the `PersonRole` status to inactive on deletion. You could try SQLAlchemy's [ORM Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#session-events) page to see if any of the events fit your need.

Comment: Thanks @Heits, I'll take a look at the documentation. The hardest part is supporting the legacy database structure.